How to color rows in Matrix Table based on cells value
I have created a table in Grafana using a SQL query & Grouping to Matrix



A/B
Col1
Col2
Col3




Row1
1.ab
2.ab
1.ab


Row2
3.nc
3.nc
3.nc



Row 1 has different values but Row 2 doesn't. How can I highlight row 1 in red and Row 2 in Green?
The values are always going to be Strings
